# Line Graph with Labeled Markers for Multiple Columns using Plotly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, plotly

I'm trying to create a line graph with labeled marker points using Plotly. I have a data frame with columns `Date`, `Percentage Change` and `Percentage Change From Initial`. I want to display all the labeled marker points at once on the graph and ensure that the markers are spaced out enough to be clearly visible.

I would like to plot the `Percentage Change` and `Percentage Change From Initial` columns as a line graph and display labeled marker points for the `Value` column. How can I achieve this using Plotly?

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

# Create a sample dataframe
data = {
    'Date': ['2023-05-01', '2023-05-02', '2023-05-03', '2023-05-04', '2023-05-05', '2023-05-06'],
    'Percentage Change': [0.0, 0.2, -0.083, 0.227, -0.037, 0.154],
    'Percentage Change From Initial': [0.0, 0.2, 0.1, 0.35, 0.3, 0.5]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Create the Plotly figure
fig = go.Figure()

# Calculate the interval for data points
interval = len(df) // 2

# Create a list of indices for the data points
indices = list(range(0, len(df), interval))

# Add Percentage Change trace with markers and labels
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['Date'], y=df['Percentage Change'], mode='lines+markers', name='Percentage Change'))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['Date'][indices], y=df['Percentage Change'][indices], mode='markers',
                         marker=dict(size=10), showlegend=False,
                         text=df['Percentage Change'][indices], hovertemplate="Percentage Change: %{text} <extra></extra>"))

# Add Percentage Change From Initial trace with markers and labels
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['Date'], y=df['Percentage Change From Initial'], mode='lines+markers',
                         name='Percentage Change From Initial'))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['Date'][indices], y=df['Percentage Change From Initial'][indices], mode='markers',
                         marker=dict(size=10), showlegend=False,
                         text=df['Percentage Change From Initial'][indices],
                         hovertemplate="Percentage Change From Initial: %{text} <extra></extra>"))

# Set the title and axis labels
fig.update_layout(title='Stock Data',
                  xaxis_title='Date',
                  yaxis_title='Percentage')

# Display the figure
fig.show()
```

**The Current Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One way to add labels is to annotate a string of text using the text mode of a scatterplot. In this case, the text can only be placed in a limited location, for example in the top centre. The second is to use the function for text annotation. This allows for more annotation positions and text decoration.

```
# Create the Plotly figure
fig = go.Figure()

# Calculate the interval for data points
interval = len(df) // 2

# Create a list of indices for the data points
indices = list(range(0, len(df), interval))

# Add Percentage Change trace with markers and labels
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['Date'],
                         y=df['Percentage Change'],
                         mode='lines+markers+text',
                         text=df['Percentage Change'],
                         textposition='top center',
                         name='Percentage Change'))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['Date'][indices],
                         y=df['Percentage Change'][indices],
                         mode='markers',
                         marker=dict(size=10),
                         showlegend=False,
                         text=df['Percentage Change'][indices],
                         hovertemplate="Percentage Change: %{text} <extra></extra>"))

# Add Percentage Change From Initial trace with markers and labels
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['Date'],
                         y=df['Percentage Change From Initial'],
                         mode='lines+markers',
                         name='Percentage Change From Initial')
             )
for i,pi in enumerate(df['Percentage Change From Initial']):
    fig.add_annotation(x=df.loc[i,'Date'],
                       xref='x',
                       y=df.loc[i,'Percentage Change From Initial'],
                       yref='y',
                       text=str(pi),
                       yshift=25,
                       showarrow=False
                       )
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['Date'][indices],
                         y=df['Percentage Change From Initial'][indices],
                         mode='markers',
                         marker=dict(size=10),
                         showlegend=False,
                         text=df['Percentage Change From Initial'][indices],
                         hovertemplate="Percentage Change From Initial: %{text} <extra></extra>")
             )

# Set the title and axis labels
fig.update_layout(title='Stock Data',
                  xaxis_title='Date',
                  yaxis_title='Percentage')

# Display the figure
fig.show()
```

[image]